# mlflow artifacts not showing up in databricks

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow

When I use the code below, the metrics, and parameters are successfully listed as artifacts in the user interface(ui). However, the training data, is not listed in the user interface(ui). Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

```
import mlflow
import mlflow.sklearn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tempfile
from numpy import savetxt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

db = load_diabetes()
X = db.data
y = db.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

with mlflow.start_run():
  # Set the model parameters.
  n_estimators = 100
  max_depth = 6
  max_features = 3

  # Create and train model.
  rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = n_estimators, max_depth = max_depth, max_features = max_features)
  rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

  # Use the model to make predictions on the test dataset.
  predictions = rf.predict(X_test) 

  # Log the model parameters used for this run.
  mlflow.log_param("num_trees", n_estimators)
  mlflow.log_param("maxdepth", max_depth)
  mlflow.log_param("max_feat", max_features)
 
  # Define a metric to use to evaluate the model.
  mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)
   
  # Log the value of the metric from this run.
  mlflow.log_metric("mse", mse)

  # Log the model created by this run.

  mlflow.sklearn.log_model(rf, "random-forest-model")

  #Log the training data
  train=pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
  with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
    path=os.path.join(tmp, 'train.csv')
    train.to_csv(path)
    mlflow.log_artifacts(tmp)
  
  mlflow.end_run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I have to convert the two parts of the dataframe to dataframes i.e.

```
X_train2=pd.DataFrame(X_train)
y_train2=pd.DataFrame(y_train)
 train=pd.concat([X_train2, y_train2], axis=1)
```